# C# read excel cannot get the value

Tags: c#, excel, oledbdatareader

I can read all of the value except 'one'.

This is my code:

```
OleDbConnection oledb_con = new OleDbConnection(strCon);

oledb_con.Open();

OleDbCommand oledb_com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]", oledb_con);

OleDbDataReader oledb_dr = oledb_com.ExecuteReader();

while (oledb_dr.Read())
{                
       ActionList.Add(oledb_dr[0].ToString().Trim());
       ValueList.Add(oledb_dr[1].ToString().Trim());
}

oledb_dr.Close();
oledb_con.Close();
```

the ValueList[0] always show nothing,but other ValueList's member can read.

And theActionList[0] can read.

why cannot the first value be read.

And how can I solve it?

Comment: Well do you have any values available (maybe the row is blank or its header row so ignored)

Comment: yes i can edit excel by myself. if header row ignored another column's header row should not be worked but only one column has problem. =(

Comment: If your column is mixtype . maybe you need add "MaxScanRows=0;IMEX=1;" in your strcon .

Comment: already add, but still have the same problem.

Comment: if you have `HDR=Yes` in your connectionstring, try by specifying the column names on your select statement instead of `*`. Ex: `SELECT MyColumn1, MyColumn2 FROM [sheet1$]`

Comment: MaxScanRows is no use unless you tamper with the registry.

Comment: It is best to post your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the value is not null? On null reading value as string fails.

```cs
oledb_dr.IsDbNull(1) ? "" : oledb_dr[1].ToString().Trim()
```